# sanitize-html npm module not working on Heroku deploy

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, heroku

I installed the sanitize-html npm library on my node.js and express application. I am working on Cloud9 IDE, which allows a preview of your site. Sanitize-html does its job and works perfectly in the preview, but when I attempt to deploy my app to the web with heroku, I get an application error. I know the error is due to sanitize-html, because when I remove it, and deploy my app, it all works fine. This is my heroku log:

```
2016-02-22T16:35:13.344238+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-02-22T16:35:14.684861+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-02-22T16:35:06.369072+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sharecookie.herokuapp.com request_id=b37b7b05-5b82-4668-80fb-5714a0ddbc61 fwd="207.74.9.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-02-22T16:35:15.916200+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-22T16:35:15.916220+00:00 app[web.1]: > node bin/www
2016-02-22T16:35:15.916221+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-22T16:35:16.489614+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-77-generic
2016-02-22T16:35:16.472662+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:341
2016-02-22T16:35:16.472665+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-02-22T16:35:16.489936+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-02-22T16:35:16.490118+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.6.0
2016-02-22T16:35:16.472666+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-02-22T16:35:16.472667+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-22T16:35:16.472668+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'sanitize-html'
2016-02-22T16:35:16.472670+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
2016-02-22T16:35:16.472670+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
2016-02-22T16:35:16.472671+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/index.js:11:20)
2016-02-22T16:35:16.472671+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-02-22T16:35:16.472672+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2016-02-22T16:35:16.472676+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:14:14)
2016-02-22T16:35:16.472677+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
```

Blah blah blah, it's saying it cannot find the 'sanitize-html' module, even though it's installed in node_modules, and referenced in my index.js as `var sanitizeHtml = require('sanitize-html');` This is really frustrating. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer browsing other questions. I needed to use `git add -A --force` to completely re-add all my modules, and that worked. Kind of odd